# Git branching strategy for parallel release lines

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

We're small team migrating to Git and I'm wondering which branching model we should choose. I read many articles online already I found out that the Gitflow as described [here](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow) or [here](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/), even if generally seems fine, may not fully suit out needs.

What I found missing is the support for 2 major releases at the same time. Let's say we have 2 parallel major release lines: 1.2.x and 2.0.x. All features from 1.2 should be eventually in 2.0, but not the other way round. 1.2 will finish earlier, then it needs to be supported for few months (bugfixing).

```
     > 1.2 features here  |> only bugfixes from now
          1.2.5  1.2.6  1.2.7   1.2.8  1.2.9 (end)
1.2.x ------o------o------O-------o------o
             \      \      \       \      \ (merge after every release)
        2.0.x \--------o----------o----------o----------o------->
                      2.0.1     2.0.1      2.0.2
                2.0 specific features
```

I was wondering how to modify Gitflow to support that. I was thinking to create 2 development branches - one for each major release, and keep merging from development 1.2 branch to development 2.0. But then I have no idea what I should put to master. Or I should have 2 master branches as well?
Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As this topic might be quite opinionated I will simple go on from you wonderings:

- **Yes** two `development` branches sounds logical in your case
- The `master` branches (two in your case) (they don't have to be named master at all) would always **reflect a production-ready state** (*like described in [A successful Git branching model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)*)

Answer (score 0):

> All features from 1.2 should be eventually in 2.0, but not the other way round. 1.2 will finish earlier, then it needs to be supported for few months (bugfixing).

The fact that gitflow is release-centric does not prevent you to merge at any time the 1.2 hotfix branch to `dev` or to `2.0` release branch. That might not be a gitflow command, but that remains a basic `git merge` one.

> I was thinking to create 2 development branches

Once you have an 1.2 hotfix branch (after a [`gitflow hotfix start`](http://danielkummer.github.io/git-flow-cheatsheet/#hotfixes)), you can keep making hotfixes, and merging them to any other branch like the 2.0 release (in addition of `master` and `dev`, which `git flow hotfix finish` does)